# Assigning database credentials

Tags: php

I have a config.ini that contains my database credentials. I retrieve them with a parser class like this:

```
public function getField($section, $field) {
    return $this->iniArray[$section][$field];
}
```

In my `DbConnect` class I do this, which seems silly:

```
public function __construct() {
    $ini = new Configuration('configs/config.ini');
    $this->host = $ini->getField('Database', 'host');
    $this->user = $ini->getField('Database', 'user');
    $this->pass = $ini->getField('Database', 'password');
    $this->dbname = $ini->getField('Database', 'name');
```

I'm sure there is a better way to set these values, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps instead of an ini file, a JSON would suit the purpose better. I've seen this multiple times, even in large, well-known PHP frameworks.

You can find a lot about [decoding JSON from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Here's a little [blog post about handling decoding](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP). And here's [a StackOverflow question regarding the external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758954/get-data-from-json-file-with-php).

---

Also, if you keep the same class, I suggest passing `Configuration` through the constructor to practice dependency injection.

```
public function __construct(Configuration $ini) {
    $this->host = $ini->getField('Database', 'host');
    $this->user = $ini->getField('Database', 'user');
    $this->pass = $ini->getField('Database', 'password');
    $this->dbname = $ini->getField('Database', 'name');
}
```

Comment: I'll look into JSON, but let's say i keep using it like this.
Isn't there a better way to set them, than to repeat the getField function 4 times?

Comment: @Donny I'm not sure it get's any better than what you have? A loop would be over-kill, a single associative array would be unclear and undefined, and a whole new object would be preposterous! Tweaking your question may bring it into scope on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) if you want to try to ask there.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to load your configuration options would be to store them in a PHP file like this

**config.php**

```
<?php

  return array(

    "host" => "localhost",
    "username" => ""
    ...
  );
```

This is more secure, fast and also PHP will tell you of any syntax errors.

---

If you insist to go with your way , You can write your `getField()` as:

```
public function getField($section, $field = false) {

    if(!$field) {

       return $this->iniArray[$section];
    }

    return $this->iniArray[$section][$field];
}
```

And in your `__construct()`:

```
public function __construct() {
    $ini = new Configuration('configs/config.ini');
    $this->DB = $ini->getField('Database');
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this method is more secure? If both are done in a sensible manner, shouldn't they have equal security?

Comment: This method is more secure because , the configuration is stored in a ``.php`` file so it will give a blank page to the browser if accessed directly . But your ``.ini`` file is treated like any other text file so it will output all the contents of the file when access directly which is very insecure **unless** you have all your ini files inaccessible from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your Database class is a Database class, not a configReader.

To perform it's database tasks. It needs 4 parameters. Without them the class has no reason to exist. Thus, we ask for them in the construct:

```
public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $dbname) {
    //connect to the db, throw an error if that fails.
}
```

The database shouldn't care where the configs are commig from. It could be hard coded, .ini file or JSON. But this has nothing to do with your Databse class. so keep it that way ;)